# Conservation of simple dot product inequalities

Tags: geometry

Let us suppose you have a mapping $~f \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ such that
$$\forall (a,b) \in (\mathbb{R}^d)^2,~\langle a-b, f(a)-f(b)\rangle \geq 0$$

Is it true that
$$\forall (a,b, c) \in (\mathbb{R}^d)^2,~\langle a-c, b-c\rangle \geq 0 \Rightarrow \langle f(a)-f(c), f(b)-(c)\rangle \geq 0$$

If no, is there an intuitive counter-example to this property ?

**Discussion**

In general for $(a,b,c) \in (\mathbb{R}^d)^3$

- $\langle a-c, f(a)-f(c)\rangle > 0$
- $\langle b-c, f(b)-f(c)\rangle > 0$
- $\langle a-c, b-c\rangle > 0$

does not implies anything about $\langle f(a) - f(c), f(b) - f(c) \rangle$.

We can maybe solve this issue by noting that $\langle a-b, f(a)-f(b)\rangle \geq 0$ holds for all couples of $\mathbb{R}^d$